# How to get user setting on OpenERP

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm developing a web module on OpenERP, and i'm having troubles with date objects as this objects are stored in UTC on the database, so i want to convert a date (also the time) according to the user configuration of openERP.

So my question is how do i get the user preferences from a web module (client side) or how can i transform the date according to the user location settings?

I don't know where to start, the only thing i have at the moment is this

```
date_start = $('span.date_start > span > .oe_datepicker_master').val();
```

Which returns me the date on format mm/dd/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :) :

```
str_to_date_format: function (date) {
    var date_pattern = Date.normalizeFormat(openerp.web.strip_raw_chars(_t.database.parameters.date_format));
    return Date.parseExact(date, (date_pattern));
},
str_to_datetime_format: function (date) {
    var date_pattern = Date.normalizeFormat(openerp.web.strip_raw_chars(_t.database.parameters.date_format)),
        time_pattern = Date.normalizeFormat(openerp.web.strip_raw_chars(_t.database.parameters.time_format));
    return Date.parseExact(date, (date_pattern + ' ' + time_pattern));
},
```